# If $X$ is a 2x3 matrix such that $|XX’|\not =0$ and $A=I-X(X’X)^{-1}X’$, then find $A^2$

Tags: matrices

$$A=I-X(X^{-1}X^{-1’})X’$$

$$A=I-I=O$$

So $A^2=O$

But the correct answer is $A$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inverse of non square matrix? You cant do $(X'X)^{-1} = X^{-1}X'^{-1}$ as $X$ is not a square matrix, so it is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^2=(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X') =$
$ I^2-IX(X'X)^{-1}X'-X(X'X)^{-1}X'I+X(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'=$
$I-2X(X'X)^{-1}X'+X(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'=$
$I-2X(X'X)^{-1}X'+X(X'X)^{-1}X'=I-X(X'X)^{-1}X'=A$.

Note that $X'X(X'X)^{-1} = I$